# Delete route not being hit in my code

Tags: python, html, url, flask

images.html

```
<body>
{% if msg %}   <h1>{{ msg }}!</h1>  {% endif %}

 <div class="container">
   <h1>Here you can upload a file</h1>
   <form id="upload_form" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" accept="uploaded_files/*" multiple>
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
   </form>
   <hr>
  <!--- <h1>Here you can download a file</h1>
   <form id="download_form" action="/download" method="POST">
     File Name: <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter file name"><br><br>

     <input type="submit" name="download" value="download">
   </form>
   <hr>
   <h1>Here you can delete a file</h1>
   <form id="delete_form" action="/delete" method="POST">
     File Name: <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Enter file name"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
   </form>
   <hr>--->
   <h1>Here you can List,Download and delete all the files</h1>
   {% if list_names %}
   {% for item in list_names %}
       <!--- <a href="/download/{{ item }}">{{ item }}</a>--->

    <img src="{{item}}" height="400px"/>
     <a href="/delete{{item}}">delete</a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

   <form id="list_form" action="/list_files" method="POST">
     <input type="submit" name="list" value="list">
   </form>
   <hr>
  </div>
 </body>
```

website.py

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request, render_template

import os
import base64
import mysql.connector
import base64




app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="mounika.cb3d7dg2fmod.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
                         user="mounika", password="mounika2061993", database="innodb")
    cur = db.cursor()
    app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'


class ServerError(Exception):pass



@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    error = None
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username_form  = request.form['username']
            data=cur.execute("select count(1) from users1 where username=%s",[username_form])
            print data
            if not cur.fetchone()[0]:
                raise ServerError('Invalid username')

            password_form  = request.form['password']
            print "SELECT password FROM users1 WHERE username=%s",[username_form]
            data1=cur.execute("SELECT password FROM users1 WHERE username=%s",[username_form])

            #print data1

            for row in cur.fetchall():
                if password_form== row[0]:
                    session['username'] = request.form['username']
                    return render_template('images.html', error=error)

            raise ServerError('Invalid password')
    except ServerError as e:
        error = str(e)



    except ServerError as e:
        error = str(e)

    return render_template('index.html', error=error)





@app.route('/')
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])
def uploaddownload():
    username_session = escape(session['username'])
    print username_session
    get_files=request.files.get('file')

    extension=os.path.splitext(get_files.filename)[1]
    print extension
    file_name = os.path.splitext(get_files.filename)[0]
    new_file_name=file_name+extension
    #dir_path = os.path.abspath(new_file_name)
    #print dir_path
    print "hi"
    print new_file_name
    print get_files

    print file_name

    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './static/Uploads'
    get_files.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], new_file_name))
    path=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+'/'+new_file_name
    print "path"
    print path
    print "file saved succesfully to local upload folder"
    extension_list=['.jpg','.jnpg','.jpeg','.png','.GIF','.BMP','.JPG','.JPNG']
    if(extension in extension_list):
        # print "hiiiiiiiii"

        sql ="INSERT INTO images1 (user_name,images) VALUES(%s,%s)"
        args=(session['username'],path,)
        data= cur.execute(sql,args)
        db.commit()

    return render_template("images.html")

@app.route('/list_files',methods=['POST'])

def list_Files():
    sql1="select images from images1"
    cur.execute(sql1)
    data= cur.fetchall()
    print data
    file_name_list=[]
    for file in data:
        #file_name_list.append(file.generate_url(3600,query_auth=False,force_http=True))
        file_name_list.append(file[0].strip('.'))
        print  file_name_list
        #print file.name
    return render_template("images.html",list_names=file_name_list)

@app.route('/delete<filename>')
def delete(filename):
    print "Hi"

    return render_template("index.html")






if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The above is my code. In my html I have included anchor tag to delete. item will give the path of the image. so when I click the anchor tage it is searching for the route as '/delete/static/Uploads/14199543_1107156822698054_3500700356588134783_n.jpg'

In my python code I have included the route @app.route('/delete'). I am expecting that the filename is going to capture the path from html. But I guess this isn't working. How can I get item from html which here is the path of the image to the python code so that I could write a delete query including it in the where clause. Or can someone pls explain how to write a delete function that deletes the image when I click the anchor tag.

My code is messy. But the list and login are working fine. Any help regarding delete is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you get an error message or does it appear like its not even calling it?

Comment: You can try
@app.route('/delete/<string:filename>')

Comment: @WhatsThePoint I get this GET /delete/static/Uploads/14199543_1107156822698054_3500700356588134783_n.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 - in my console and in my web browser I get "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." So I guess the route is not getting hit

Comment: [This](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/) might fix your problem.

Comment: @syntonym it worked!! Thank you :)